# How to make API GET requests with no API Public Key

Tags: python-2.7, python-requests, api-design

I am trying to extract data from an API but in the documentation I was only given one API key, which I assume is the private key.

If this is the case how do I make a GET call in python to pull out data for say inventory based on below documentation documentation(can not post entire document) and if no URL is provided?:

```
Public Inventory API
 1.0 
[ Base url: https://partner-gateway.staging.mjplatform.com/v1] https://partners.mjfreeway.com/docs/inventory
API data related to inventory management

Schemes

catalog

GET
/catalog
Listing of Sellable Products
This request provides a detailed listing of all sellable products, also referred to throughout the system as "item masters", for the active facility. The listing can be filtered by some simple parameters.
Parameters
Name    Description
category_id
integer
(query) 
The ‘id’ of a single category to which you want to limit results
subcategory_id
integer
(query) 
The ‘id’ of a single subcategory to which you want to limit results
strain_id
integer
(query) 
The ‘id’ of a single strain to which you want to limit results
item_number
string
(query) 
The item number of a particular item master, i.e. BKSA00000003
uom_type
string
(query) 
The method of measurement for the item. Valid options are discrete, weight, and volume
available_online
boolean
(query) 
A boolean indicator of whether the item can be sold online
```

This is my code so far:

```
import requests

# api-endpoint
URL = "https://www.mjplatform.com/catalog"

# location given here
key = "123abc"

# defining a params dict for the parameters to be sent to the API
PARAMS = {URL:key}

# sending get request and saving the response as response object
r = requests.get(url = URL, params = PARAMS)

# extracting data in json format
data = r.json()
```

When I run the above I get the following message:

```
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

I am not sure what I am doing to get the data if I am getting a response status 200.

Edit:

Ran print(r.text) got this message:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title>MJ Platform</title><link href="/main.b21e9284629fc8bfb7bc9b4158ad44b9.css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="defaultLoadingMessage"><div style="height:40px"></div><div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><div><h1 style="text-align:center">Loading MJ Platform</h1><div class="text-muted" style="text-align:center;width:600px;margin:auto;color:#aaa">If you continue to see this message for more than a few seconds, your browser is most likely out of date or incompatible. We support Chrome and Firefox. Other browsers may work but not provide an optimal experience. <strong>Safari and MS IE are specifically not supported.</strong></div></div></div></div><div id="app"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/main.cccbe56cf819e9f8a6e3.js"></script></body></html>
```

How can browser be out of date, if I pulling information into a python anaconda window?

Comment: execute `print(r.text)`

Comment: made a edit, ran print(r.text) got message saying browser out of date(above). How can that be if data is coming into python anaconda module?

Comment: Don't know anaconda, but if it's a JSON API wouldn't you want to make a JSON GET?

Comment: I have reviewed that page and you need to be authenticated with a token which I do not see in your request. Do you have a token?

Comment: @DaveNewton can you give an example of JSON get? I have cURL examples in the documentation, is that same thing?

Comment: @eyllanesc I am trying to figure out why no token is provided. Documentation is sparse.

Comment: You could tell me where I find that docs, maybe find a way to do it. If you enter the link: https://www.mjplatform.com/catalog and impenicionas and check the console you will get the following: `Uncaught InvalidTokenError {message: "Invalid token specified"}message: "Invalid token .....ick @ TimeoutModalContainer.js:113`

Comment: @eyllanesc thats the thing, the documentation is behind a login for work. I think you are correct there needs to be a token. Let me follow up and recontact you.

Answer (score 0):

Was given other API information not included in documentation.